# калькулятор java. в чем ошибка?

Tags: java, swing

Пытался написать "калькулятор" и что бы фрэйм и слушатель были в отдельных классах, но что то ничего не происходит при проверке, то есть кнопка `b1` на которую прилепил `addActionListener(listener)` не работает то есть добавил текстфилд который должен заполниться ответом но этого не происходит.

Сам листенер получен путём создания его экземпляра и проинициализирован в мэйн классе, и через метод сетЛистенер добавлен в фрэйм, и по аналогии так же проинициализированный фрэйм находится в классе листенер, то есть имеют экземпляры друг друга.

Да конечно калькулятор состоит из одной кнопки и ответом должно быть введённое увеличенное число на единицу. И то что написано наверняка по нубски, на это можете не обращать внимания. Главное подскажите где ошибка.

При написании аналогичного с классом фрэйм и вложенным в него листенера все работает норма.

**Основной класс:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class MainCalc {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Listener listener = new Listener();
        Frame frame = new Frame("windows self 1/33.3");
        frame.setListener(listener);
        listener.setFrame(frame);
        listener.getFrame().setVisible(true);
        listener.getFrame().setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        listener.getFrame().setSize(200, 200);
        listener.getFrame().setResizable(false);
        listener.getFrame().setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

**Листенер:**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Listener implements ActionListener{
    private Frame fr = null;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         try {
             if(e.getSource() == fr.b1){
                 int i = Integer.parseInt(fr.tm.getText());
                 i++;
                 String a = ""+i;
                 fr.lm.setText(a);
             }
         } catch (Exception e1) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter NUMBER");
         }
     }

     public Frame getFrame(){
         return fr;
     }

     public void setFrame(Frame fr) {
         this.fr = fr;
     }
}
```

**Класс фрэйм:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Frame extends JFrame{
    JButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b0, bm, bp, bdot, beq, bmul, bdiv;
    JTextField tm, tme1, tme2;
    JLabel lm;
    private Listener listener = null;

    public void setListener(Listener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public Listener getListener(){
        return listener;
    }

    public Frame(String s){
        super(s);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        b1 = new JButton("unit");
        tm = new JTextField(10);
        lm = new JLabel("text here");
        add(b1); add(tm); add(lm);
        b1.addActionListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Comment: swing уже давно не развивается, лучше, пока не поздно, переходите на javafx. Ну и в целов оно куда удобнее и гибче

Comment: спасибо. думал разбираться со всем в порядке очереди :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема в том, что вы вызываете

```
b1.addActionListener(listener);
```

До того как поместите в `listener` ваш объект. Поэтому при нажатии на кнопку обработчик не вызывается.

Выносить слушатель в отдельный класс не обязательно. Лучше почитайте про паттерн **MVC** и попробуйте разобраться в нем. Вот мой пример демонстрирующий реализацию MVC [SimpleMVC](https://github.com/Vaysman/SimpleMVC)

Comment: спасибо. но почему то когда через дебаг запускал и с точки остановки начинал пошагово. то показывалось что класс фрейм получал инициализированный листенер, и тот же самый листенер получал b1.addActionListener(listener); ******** где вместо звёздочек писался класс объекта с номером, то есть естественно при первом вызове был нулл, а потом уже присвоение инициализированного листенера.

Comment: вероятно у вас был другой код или это ошибка в отладчике.